# Excel 2016 - User-defined type not defined

Tags: excel, vba

Am stumped with a BingMaps API Compile error, 
Basically it runs in Microsoft Office 2010 without issue, 
however when I try and run this in Office 2016 it fails to run and thought's a vba debug error.

```
Function GetDistance(sPCode As String, ePcode As String) As Double
    Dim t As String
    Dim re As XMLHTTP

    t = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes/Driving?o=xml&wp.0=" & sPCode & "&wp.1=" & ePcode & "&avoid=minimizeTolls&du=mi&key=AjfyHbOP6UDABNbXmV59momsvs6cRqjrIz4g0bbsmGyBAJz1TgTgqRXS_PfWcm5k"

    Set re = New XMLHTTP

    re.Open "get", t, False
    re.send
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until re.readyState = 4

    With re
        s = Split(.responseText, "<TravelDistance>")
    End With

    GetDistance = Val(s(1))

End Function
```

Comment: What is the error and on what line?

Comment: Check to ensure all your needed references are set. What is likely happening is XMLHTTP is not recognized as a valid Type. This could happen if the needed libraries for the XMLHTTP Type aren't included. Do you get intellisense when defining re as XMLHTTP? What about when using properties of re? If not, then the compiler doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @ScottCraner http://imgur.com/a/6AQPF this is the error code from the Debug in Excel 2016

Comment: @BrandonBarney When I used it in Office 2010 I only had to enable the Microsofto XML , 6.0 which made it work, so am not sure why its stopped and its above me to resolve, hence why I brought it to you guys :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem!

Not sure if this will work for you, but on tools, references deselect Microsoft XML V6 and select V3.0.

that's worked for me.

Regards